# jQuery jsonp caching, is there a way to change timestamp url key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, jsonp

Hello I'm creating a jsonp api and I'm using `cache = false` in my `$.ajax()` settings. However my server requires a specific prefix in front of every url `GET` parameter.

ex. `http://www.domain.com/test?_prefix_age=29`

I have accomplished such a thing but I cant find a way to add my prefix in the caching timestamp parameter `_:{TIMESTAMP}`

From jQuery `$.ajax()` docs:

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp') Type:
>   Boolean If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

Is there any way I could add the prefix infront of the timestamp parameter without messing up jQuery internally ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just not use jQuery. Example:

```
<script>
function processJSON (json) {
  // Do something with the JSON response
};

// Create a new script element
var script_element = document.createElement('script');

// Set its source to the JSONP API
script_element.src = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=processJSON&tags=monkey&tagmode=any&format=json';

// Stick the script element in the page <head>
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script_element);
</script>
```

The barrier to create your own JSONP function might be low enough to skip trying to make jquery work?

Taken from http://schock.net/articles/2013/02/05/how-jsonp-really-works-examples/